# "Array" detection in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

Can Tensorflow handle inputs of varying shapes (sizes)?

#### The project

I'm developing a image/shape recognizer which captures an array of `{x:#,y:#}` positions.

For example, a circle might look like this

```
[{"x":0.38,"y":0.32},{"x":0.33,"y":0.35},{"x":0.31,"y":0.4},{"x":0.31,"y":0.46},{"x":0.34,"y":0.51},{"x":0.39,"y":0.52},{"x":0.44,"y":0.51},{"x":0.47,"y":0.47},{"x":0.49,"y":0.42},{"x":0.47,"y":0.37},{"x":0.42,"y":0.34},{"x":0.37,"y":0.33}]
```

and a square like this

```
[{"x":0.15,"y":0.19},{"x":0.15,"y":0.25},{"x":0.15,"y":0.31},{"x":0.15,"y":0.37},{"x":0.14,"y":0.42},{"x":0.14,"y":0.48},{"x":0.14,"y":0.53},{"x":0.14,"y":0.59},{"x":0.14,"y":0.64},{"x":0.2,"y":0.64},{"x":0.26,"y":0.64},{"x":0.31,"y":0.65},{"x":0.37,"y":0.65},{"x":0.43,"y":0.65},{"x":0.49,"y":0.65},{"x":0.54,"y":0.65},{"x":0.6,"y":0.65},{"x":0.65,"y":0.65},{"x":0.67,"y":0.6},{"x":0.68,"y":0.55},{"x":0.68,"y":0.5},{"x":0.68,"y":0.44},{"x":0.68,"y":0.38},{"x":0.68,"y":0.32},{"x":0.67,"y":0.27},{"x":0.67,"y":0.22},{"x":0.66,"y":0.17},{"x":0.61,"y":0.15},{"x":0.56,"y":0.13},{"x":0.51,"y":0.13},{"x":0.45,"y":0.13},{"x":0.39,"y":0.13},{"x":0.33,"y":0.13},{"x":0.27,"y":0.13},{"x":0.22,"y":0.14},{"x":0.17,"y":0.15}]
```

Because the length of these shapes can vary I was wondering how Tensorflow would handle it...as I understand it, the input "shape" needs to always be the same length, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the shape should be the same. But, in your case, you can make sure that for a batch, all the arrays have the same number of elements by adding dummy elements to those which fall short in length.

Just make sure that for a batch, your shape is same.