# Handling ragged data in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

A follow-up question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62486994/array-detection-in-tensorflow)

I have 'Ragged' data.
e.g. this would be 3 different things I want to build my model from

```
[
[[0.3,0.3,-90],[0.33,0.4,-95],[0.3,1.3,-87]], // example 1
[[0.3,0.3,-90],[0.33,0.4,-95],[0.33,0.4,-95],[0.3,1.3,-87]], // example 2
[[0.33,-0.4,95],[-0.3,1.3,67]]  // example 3
]
```

I understand that most datasets are fixed lengths like image recognition of `28 x 28` pixels and that

I'm a bit lost with using ragged data and how I can begin building my model.

Does anyone know of some followup reading I can do after [ragged tensors](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor)?

Comment: I have a feeling you could feed it in like time-series data using LSTMs.

Comment: did you consider using dummy data such as `[0,0,0]`  in between to fix the length?

Comment: I have considered it however there is a potential that a few bits of data will be quite long which would result in everything being required to scale up a lot.

I'm very much a beginner with Tensorflow so perhaps using dummy data is actually the right route to take.